# a:hover not working as intended in WebKit

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

html {
  background-color: #13315C;
  color: #CED0CE;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.text {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #F5F5F5;
  text-decoration-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

a {
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

a:visited {
  color: #CED0CE;
}

ul>ul {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #F5F5F5 !important;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://example.jpg" alt="me" width="100" style="padding-right: 200px">
  <div class="center text" style="width: 58%">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <h2 class="center">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum <a href="https://example.org">Lorem Ipsum</a> 2021 - 2025</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="center">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  <p>lorem<a href="https://example.org">example.org</a> lorem ispum</p>
  <p></p>

</main>
```

The first  has the colour F5F5F5 on hover, but the second , even made sure that I visited the site does not, the colour doesn’t change

I have this issue happening only in WebKit. Tried this code in Firefox, Brave, Chrome and it works as intended. Any ideas on what’s the cause/fix? Thank you!